# Change the default color of top border line of UItabbar

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode7

Hello can anybody help me it would be greatly appreciated, I wanted to know how do you change the color of the default grey stroke on top of the UItab bar I also wanted the stroke to be 2px. I tried various methods of coding I place this code in the view controller:

self.tabBarController!.tabBar.layer.borderWidth = 0.50
self.tabBarController!.tabBar.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor

and it placed a stroke around the entire tab bar. I would like a 2px stroke on top with a custom rgb color of: red: 208, green: 28,blue: 28

Such as picture below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4AKm.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Possible options:

- Use a (stretchable) background image for the tabBar
- It's not recommended playing with existing UI elements, but you may try simply adding a new sub view with the same width as the Tab Bar, 2 pixels high, the color you want as background, placed at (0,0)

Comment: how do I make sure the image stretches in the background?

Comment: See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/chapters/SlicinganImage.html and https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/ResizableImages.html

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `UITabBar`s `shadowImage` property!

Comment: is there some code I would need to enter or is that build within the xcode interface.